# Using private fields in the grails controller

Tags: grails

I know that `service` in grails is singleton by default.

Is it bad practice to use private fields in controller/service? Could anyone explain, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controllers are not singletons by default. They are created for each request. Services are, by default singletons. It's not bad practice to use private fields in Services. It's fairly common that Services have private fields to hold configuration state at runtime.

I suspect your concern is about using private fields as a means of storing state for a particular request within a Service. Which is obviously bad considering there could be N requests being serviced by the Service. So long as you are using private fields to control the service from an application perspective and not a request perspective you will be fine.

**Edit (further information)**
As stated, services can and often do have private members. However, you should never use these as a means for storing information about the current request being processed. Obviously, since this is a singleton that would cause interleaving issues. Only use private members to store information that is visible across all requests. Typically these will be configuration settings of the service itself.

It's best to make your service stateless in regards to the requests they are processing. Any state you need should be encapsulated in the parameter(s) or input/output of your Service methods. Services should act on data, not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes, my concern is about multiple requests and if service have a state there can be another request, so how to aboid this? is it better to make service stateless?

Comment: I will post an edit to include some further information to answer this as well.

Comment: thanks, now it's clear. and what about `controllers`? is using private fields in controller a horrible thing? (I never used it, but seen in the code)

Comment: Controllers are request scoped, so no it's not a horrible thing, but it's frowned upon because it can make things unclear.

Comment: So, if I need to share common data between several actions in controller, can I use private fields in controller instead of invoking service methods in every action? Is it a good practice?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and sorry for newbie questions :)

Comment: No worries, I don't mind helping you learn. I really would avoid using private members within a controller for storing state. I would look at using the chain or forward methods to sequence the actions together. Both of these can be found in the Grails documentation online. However, if you insist on using private members, I would do some quick tests to make sure they will behave exactly the way you expect them to. Remember each request will create and destroy a controller as it's needed.

Comment: It's great, thanks for your help! I have another question, I hope, last. If controller by default per-request, is it right, that using of multiple private methods in controller will speed down application?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51869/discussion-between-joshua-moore-and-baxxabit)